# Remove a user from the list with PUT? In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, put

I am creating a web app. Where, I have a backend api that I am using the GET method to receive my users, and on one page I have the users information, where I have a confirm button. What I want to do with the Confirm Button is when I am getting a 200 from the PUT, I want to remove the user from the list. I tried, but I need some help. Thanks in advance.

> Here is my code.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="person in userInfo.lawyers | filter : {id: lawyerId}">

<a class="back" href="#/lawyer">Back</a>

  <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
    Edit
  </button>

  <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">Save</button>

  <a class="delete" ng-click="confirmClick(); confirmedAction(person);" confirm-click>Confirm</a>



  <div class="people-view">

    <h2 class="name">{{person.firstName}}</h2>

    <h2 class="name">{{person.lastName}}</h2>

    <span class="title">{{person.email}}</span>

    <span class="date">{{person.website}} </span>


</div>

  <div class="list-view">

    <form>

      <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

        <legend>Basic Info</legend>

        <b>First Name:</b>

        <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstName">
        <br>

        <b>Last Name:</b>

        <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName">
        <br>

        <b>Email:</b>

        <input type="email" ng-model="person.email">


        <br>

      </fieldset>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> Service

```
    app.factory('people', function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.getUserInfo = function () {
        return $http.get('https://api-dev.mysite.io/admin/v1/unconfirmed_lawyers');
    };

    service.confirmUser = function (lawyerId) {
        return $http.put('https://api-dev.mysite.io/admin/v1/lawyers/{lawyerId}/confirm');




    };


    this.isChild = function(destinationId, folders){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return $http({
            method: "PUT",
            url: 'https://api-dev.mysite.io/admin/v1/lawyers/{lawyerId}/confirm'+destinationId,
            data: {folders: folders}
        }).then(function(response){
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }, function(response){
            deferred.reject(response);
            return deferred.promise;
        });
    };




    return service;




});
```

> App.js

```
     var app = angular.module("Portal", ['ngRoute',  'ui.bootstrap' ]);



app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.inactive = true;

    $scope.confirmedAction = function(person) {


    $scope.userInfo.lawyers.splice(person.id, 1);

    location.href = '#/lawyer';








};

});
```

Directive

```
app.directive('confirmClick', ['$q', 'dialogModal', function($q, dialogModal) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // ngClick won't wait for our modal confirmation window to resolve,
            // so we will grab the other values in the ngClick attribute, which
            // will continue after the modal resolves.
            // modify the confirmClick() action so we don't perform it again
            // looks for either confirmClick() or confirmClick('are you sure?')
            var ngClick = attrs.ngClick.replace('confirmClick()', 'true')
                .replace('confirmClick(', 'confirmClick(true,');

            // setup a confirmation action on the scope
            scope.confirmClick = function(msg) {
                // if the msg was set to true, then return it (this is a workaround to make our dialog work)
                if (msg===true) {
                    return true;
                }
                // msg can be passed directly to confirmClick('Are you sure you want to confirm?')
                // in ng-click
                // or through the confirm-click attribute on the
                // <a confirm-click="Are you sure you want to confirm?"></a>
                msg = msg || attrs.confirmClick || 'Are you sure you want to confirm?';
                // open a dialog modal, and then continue ngClick actions if it's confirmed
                dialogModal(msg).result.then(function() {
                    scope.$eval(ngClick);
                });
                // return false to stop the current ng-click flow and wait for our modal answer
                return false;
            };
        }
    }
}])
```

Modal service

```
/*
 Modal confirmation dialog window with the UI Bootstrap Modal service.
 This is a basic modal that can display a message with yes or no buttons.
 It returns a promise that is resolved or rejected based on yes/no clicks.
 The following settings can be passed:

 message         the message to pass to the modal body
 title           (optional) title for modal window
 okButton        text for YES button. set false to not include button
 cancelButton    text for NO button. ste false to not include button

 */
.service('dialogModal', ['$modal', function($modal) {
    return function (message, title, okButton, cancelButton) {
        // setup default values for buttons
        // if a button value is set to false, then that button won't be included
        cancelButton = cancelButton===false ? false : (cancelButton || 'No');
        okButton = okButton ===false ? false : (okButton || 'Yes');

        // setup the Controller to watch the click
        var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, settings) {
            // add settings to scope
            angular.extend($scope, settings);
            // yes button clicked
            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close(true);
            };
            // no button clicked
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        };

        // open modal and return the instance (which will resolve the promise on ok/cancel clicks)
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: '<div class="dialog-modal"> \
              <div class="modal-header" ng-show="modalTitle"> \
                  <h3 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h3> \
              </div> \
              <div class="modal-body">{{modalBody}}</div> \
              <div class="modal-footer"> \
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" ng-show="okButton">{{okButton}}</button> \
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()" ng-show="cancelButton">{{cancelButton}}</button> \
              </div> \
          </div>',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                settings: function() {
                    return {
                        modalTitle: title,
                        modalBody: message,
                        okButton: okButton,
                        cancelButton: cancelButton
                    };
                }
            }
        });

        return modalInstance;
    }
}])
```

CONFIG

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/lawyer", {
        controller: "HomeController",
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
    })
    .when("/lawyer/:id", {
        controller: "LawyerController",
        templateUrl: "partials/about.html"

    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/lawyer'

    });

});
```

> home.html

```
<div class="people"  ng-repeat="person in userInfo.lawyers | filter:userSearch" >



   <a href="#/lawyer/{{ person.id }}">


    <span class="name">{{person.firstName}} </span>
    <span class="name">{{person.lastName}} </span>

   <p class="title">{{person.email}} </p>



</a>


</div>
```

> HomeController

```
    var isConfirmed = false;
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, people, $http) {
   if (!isConfirmed) {
        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {

      $scope.userInfo = response.data;





        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
   }
});
```

> LawyerCOntroller

```
app.controller('LawyerController', ['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope, people, $routeParams) {

        $scope.lawyerId = $routeParams.id;
        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
            $scope.userInfo = response.data;
        });



    }]);
```

Comment: why you dont use delete method ?

Comment: can you please show me a code prior to my code above?